# Printf behaviour and casting

Tags: c++, c

in this code:

```
char t = 200;
printf("%u \n",t);
printf("%u \n",(unsigned char)t);
```

output is this:

4294967240

200

Why first `printf` prints some random value? Was %u specifier *alone* not enough to interpret the number as unsigned? and print 200?
Why does the cast help in the second case? What is happening under the hood?

Comment: it's not a "random value". It's undefined behavior if `char` is signed (which it appears to be).

Comment: Actually neither is technically defined because in both cases the argument is promoted to int (default argument promotions) and `%u` expects an unsigned int (unless sizeof(char)==sizeof(int))

Comment: the parameter 'u%' is expecting a unsigned decimal integer.  That is 4 bytes in size.  That is why the first printf outputs a random, large value.  The second printf is being told the the 't' is only one byte.

Comment: @PascalCuoq positive values of signed int must have a representation which is valid for the same value of unsigned int.  Also if we're getting technical , even using `t` with `%d` is undefined because the standard says that the argument must be `int` (not "the argument after default argument promotions are applied" or anything).

Comment: @user3629249 `unsigned char` is promoted to `int` when used in a function call not matching a typed parameter

Comment: @MattMcNabb If think it is fair to assume that the rules that define `printf` apply after the default arguments have taken place—I am seriously thinking about submitting a DR(?)—but on the other hand, I think that the standard is worded so as to allow a platform to use different registers to pass `int` and `unsigned int` arguments. This doesn't contradict the “representation” blurb but means that this platform would rightfully output garbage if passed an `int` (or an `unsigned char` if the latter promotes to `int`) for `%u`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I see, thanks for the explain. Would be interesting to see the comments on a DR . Is there any platform ever that would have its printf implementation check a different register for `int` than `unsigned int` ?

Answer (score 7):

The C standard doesn't specify whether ordinary `char` is a `signed` or an `unsigned` type. Some compilers treat it as a `signed` while others treat it as `unsigned` type.

It seems that `char` is `signed` by default on your implementation. `signed char` can hold value between `-128 to 127` only.

> Why first printf prints some random value?

The reason that you are getting random value is because of **undefined behavior** of the program.

> Was `%u` specifier alone not enough to interpret the number as unsigned? and print 200?

No. No type promotion inside `printf` function. 
**C11: 7.29.2 p(9):**

> **If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined**.<sup>335)</sup>

If you declare

```
double f = 5.7;
```

and use `%d` to print `f`, then you might expect that you will get an `int` value.

```
printf("%d", f) // Undefined behavior.
```

but it will invoke undefined behavior.

> Why does the cast help in the second case? What is happening under the hood?

It helps in nothing. Once you get undefined behavior, all bets are off.

Comment: I know about the range, but that's what confused me, why second line print 200 if it can't fit in char then? and like I said why only %u alone is not enough to achieve same result as second line?

Comment: @dmcr_code: Because a `signed char` will get converted to a `signed int` (and its actual value is negative, because a `signed char` cannot represent the value of `200` on your system). The `unsigned char` cast changes the conversion to an unsigned int --- and you are printing an unsigned int.

Comment: if i understood what haccks said correctly, its because signed t holds the value of 200, which isnt a valid value for a signed char. that value doesnt go away though, so when you cast it to an unsigned char, the value is valid, and will thus print the value correctly

Comment: @TimČas: Ok, but then why it didn't print the negative number? (first line). and print some random value. I have a feeling my question is not understood exactly here ... :|

Comment: @dmcr_code: Because `%u` is a specifier for an *unsigned* integer. Try `%d` or `%i` (see `printf` documentation, such as a manpage). The function doesn't "know" it's being passed a signed integer --- it thinks it's unsigned (because of `%u`).

Comment: @TimČas: Basically I asked why ONLY %u on first printf, is not enough to achieve same result as second printf?

Comment: @TimČas: If it thinks its unsigned, why it doesn't print 200 then?

Comment: @dmcr_code: I guess I'll have to create my own answer to explain this more thoroughly. Sorry haccks, I tried =\

Comment: @TimČas: please just keep in mind I know signed range is -128,127. I was interested: (1) why in first line we can't achieve same result as in second one?

Comment: @haccks: Yes, but please see comment below which indicated 4294967240 has such representation that last byte resembles 200 - for me it seems too much coincidence for it to be result of ub

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things going on here.

1. **`char` on your system is `signed` by default** (this is implementation-defined, it just happens to be so on your system)
2. the above means it can **only hold values -128 to +127** (assuming x86 architecture), so this:

   ```
   /*signed*/ char t = 200;
   ```

   ... is actually interpreted as this:

   ```
   char t = (signed char)200; /* actual value: -56 */
   ```

   so that's why `t` is negative.
3. when you pass in `t` to `printf()`, it gets promoted to a **`signed int`**, whilst maintaining its value (`-56`)

   - the promotion is a property of **variadic functions** (`printf` being one of them; see note below)
   - however, `printf()` is expecting an `unsigned int` (because you're using `%u` and not `%d`), and thus interprets the integer as that (signed `-56` and unsigned `4294967240` have the same representation in x86)
4. casting `t` to `unsigned char` actually does two things:

   - it converts the `-56` back to `+200` (since `-56` cannot be represented by a `signed char`); this is because of the `unsigned char`
   - the `+200` is extended to fill an **`unsigned int`**. This is because `printf` is a variadic function

(* note: for an explaination and examples of variadic functions in C, see this WP entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Example_in_C)

(* note2: I've simplified some things here for the same of brevity and understanding; C standard does not, for example, require that `char` is 8-bit --- but it is in most modern systems)

Comment: I think if you see my answer and look at this problem in terms of binary, this can be easily explained.

Comment: @TimČas: ok I will explore this answer more and hope it answers my questions. Main confusion still seems to be: In both cases, t has same binary representation right? Just in first case it is incorrectly interpreted, and in the second case correctly

Comment: @TimČas: Yes, but *why* that was my issue. Why in first case it is incorrectly interpreted, and in the second case correctly?

Comment: @dmcr_code; When there is UB, anything could happen.

Comment: @haccks: Yeah, we all know what UB did to the dinosaurs. A cautionary tale, that one.

Comment: @haccks: a ok, but seems you didn't see my comment, where one commenter suggested 4294967240 contains 200 as last byte - if interpreted as binary, for me it is too much coincidence for UB to print it, isn't it?

Comment: @dmcr_code: The only UB here is your initialization of `t`, because 200 is out of range. In your case, `t` is set to the bit pattern `11001000` (which would be 200 if `t` was unsigned), which represents the value -56 if interpreted as a `signed char`. A cast to an unsigned integer type means: Let **m** be the maximum of that type (here: **m=255**); if the value is positive, **m+1** is subtracted repeatedly until the value fits into the new type; otherwise, **m+1** is added until the value is in range. In your case: -56 + 256 = 200, which is in range, so `(unsigned char)-56` evaluates to 200.

Comment: @mafso: I'm pretty sure using `%u` in printf for signed integers is also UB, but I might be mistaken (too lazy to go check the Cstd right now).

Comment: @TimČas: so you say 4294967240 gets printed due to UB, and not because 4294967240 suspiciously resembles 200 closely (I mean last byte of 4294967240 seems to be 200)?. ps on my calculator -56 is shown as 0011 1000

Comment: @TimČas: C99 7.15.1.1 p.2. You're probably right, I thought, passing signed and fetching as unsigned via `va_arg` was allowed (I feel, it's a little strange that it isn't, as you can reinterpret every signed value as a value of the corresponding unsigned type).

Comment: @dmcr_code: It gets printed because, well, see my answer (which holds for the x86 and amd64 architectures). The fact that it's UB ("undefined behavior") means that the standard doesn't guarantee that this will happen (it could blow up the entire planet, or format your hard drive, as far as the standard is concerned). It doesn't crash simply because the compiler writers didn't bother checking for that error (and in fact couldn't --- it would be impractical). Doesn't mean it *won't* crash though (or format your HDD, for that matter... On some weird system).

Comment: @mafso: Isn't reinterpreting also a problem when the value cannot be represented? Keep in mind that `int` in C can have padding bits as well, which makes reinterpretation... interesting.

Comment: @TimČas: OK I will get back to this later as I am losing the point and not following all of you. I think least lesson I can take from here is use correct specifier in printf.

Comment: @dmcr_code: One more thing; practical C code ("in the real world") almost always contains UB. Either unintentional (bugs), or intentional (if somebody is targeting a specific architecture and/or implementation, and *knows* how a certain thing behaves there --- but that is a dangerous thing to do and should only be done if one is sure he knows what he's doing).

Comment: @TimČas: I want to avoid UB Of course. Just I am confused why 4294967240 is printed. Also -56 seemed to be 0011 1000 on my calculator which is not similar to 200

Comment: @TimČas: Great, a language-lawyer debate :) C99 6.2.6.2 p.2 about signed integer types: _“[…] Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding unsigned type […]”_. So, if you have an `int`, say `n`, reinterpreting by `*(unsigned *)&n` is OK (but not the other way round, if `u` is an `unsigned int`, then `*(int *)&u` may be a trap representation).

Comment: @mafso: Ah right, I forgot about that little detail. You win an internet cookie!

Comment: @dmcr_code: `111000` is 56 if interpreted as binary, not -56. Maybe your calculator gives the binary representation of the magnitude? And read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/Two's_complement) or something else about 2's complement. And have a look at my first comment, what a cast to an unsigned type does (ignoring padding bits, that's the same as converting to 2's complement). You'll also understand why assigning 200 to a `signed char` is the same as assigning -56 with your compiler.

Comment: @dmcr_code - `0011 1000` is `+56`. (0011 = 3) * 16 + (1000 = 8) = 56. If you make it negative then you will have to get `2`s complement of 56 plus 1. `0011 1000` is `1100 0111` in 2's complement. Add 1 then you have `1100 1000`. This is the representation of both 200 and -56 in an 8 bit char.

Comment: @alvits: strangely 0011 1000 is printed for 56 also on my calculator, I maybe using it wrongly. So the fact that 4294967240 is printed is not coincidence as it appears and there is reason to it?

Comment: @dmcr_code - Your calculator is not printing the actual binary value. It is printing human readable absolute (or magnitude) value and then prepending it with minus `-` sign. The seemingly random number isn't random afterall and neither was it coincidental. It's the actual representation after promotion to signed int.

Comment: Where you say "actual value: -56", it is implementation-defined in C (and may raise a signal)

Comment: "the +200 is extended to fill an unsigned int" - no, it is promoted to `int`  (the signed version). Unless we are on one of those DSPs where `sizeof(unsigned char) == sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Inside of a variable argument function, all integral types that are passed in are automatically promoted to the longest integral type that the system supports. This means that single byte `char` types are promoted to 32 bit or 64 bit types on modern x86 computers when passed into a function like `printf`. I know for a fact that GCC's `char` (and evidently whatever compiler you're using, too) defaults to being signed, so your value of 200 is actually -56 in a 2's compliment signed integer scheme.

---

Let's first take a look at why first casting it to an `unsigned char` prints 200 like expected.

The binary representation for the value 200 is `11001000`. That value is 8 bits wide, and you set a signed 8 bit type to this value.

In 2's compliment arithmetic, that same binary value actually represents -56.

Casting that byte to an unsigned type would still be `11001000`, but it would change the meaning of it back to 200.

If you promote that to a 32 bit value using unsigned arithmetic, that would become `00000000 00000000 00000000 11001000`

That 32 bit value still represents the value 200, and printing it as an unsigned value will indeed show 200.

---

Now let's look at the case where you aren't casting it.

The binary representation for the value 200 is `11001000`. That value is 8 bits wide, and you set a signed 8 bit type to this value.

In 2's compliment arithmetic, that same binary value actually represents -56.

If you promote that to a 32 bit value using 2's compliment arithmetic, that would become the binary value `11111111 11111111 11111111 11001000`

That 32 bit value still represents -56 in 2's compliment arithmetic. However, by printing it as an unsigned integer, you've made the compiler reinterpret a 32 bit signed value as a 32 bit unsigned value. For any non-negative signed value, this works as expected. However, all of those leading `1`s in the 2's compliment negative value now represent a very large unsigned type.

---

If I punch that 32 bit representation of -56 into a binary-to-unsigned-decimal converter, I get the value 4,294,967,240 - which is the value you said you were getting by calling `printf("%u", -52);`

In the case of `printf`, you're really expected to know how to treat the data that's being passed in. All that `printf` sees in the argument list is a long binary blob; it doesn't even know how many arguments there are. The format string is supposed to tell `printf` how to interpret that binary blob of data. There's absolutely no type checking that `printf` can perform. If you tell it to read an integer from the binary blob, it will try to render the next `sizeof(int)` bytes as an integer, even if the binary data is actually intended to represent a `float`.

In this case, you've passed in a single `signed char` to `printf`, which caused the binary blob to contain contain a signed 32 bit integer, and you've told `printf` that it's actually an unsigned 32 bit integer. There's no way for `printf` to tell that it should actually be a `signed char`.

Answer (score -1):

That is because `char` is a byte. 200 in binary is `11001000`. `int` is at least 16 bits wide. When you cast `%u`, it becomes `unsigned int`.

4294967240 in binary is `11111111111111111111111111001000`.

`11111111-11111111-11111111-11001000`

If you look at the last 2 bytes, that is the same as 200 in binary.

This is assuming OP is using x86 system.

Comment: "int is 4 bytes" - or maybe it is not.

Comment: How is int not 4 bytes?

Comment: And this is the exact reason why OP is seeing this phenomenon.

Comment: because it needn't be 4 bytes. the only thing that the Standard guarantees is its range (from -32767 to +32767). This means that an `int` is at least 16 bits wide. It may be more, but it's not sure. Also, a byte may or may not be an octet, so even on a system which has 32-bit long `int`s, its size may not be 4 bytes.

Comment: @user3477950,drum: For example, there exist systems with 32-bit `char`s (mostly embedded DSP devices); or 9-bit `char`s and 36-bit `int`s

Comment: I made some corrections that removes the ambiguity. However, aside from the subtle differences, this is why OP was seeing the phenomenon.

Comment: @drum: up in discussion it is suggested it is due to UB that 4294967240 is printed ... will look later at question too with fresher mind, a bit confused now

Comment: The value `200` when stored in a `signed char` sets the sign bit to `1`. This is equivalent to storing `-56` to the same signed char. When  signed variables are promoted, the signness is preserved leading to all `1`s pre-pended to the value. `%u` treats the sign bit as part of the integer hence the seemingly random value.

Comment: @alvits: -56 is shown as  0011 1000 on my calculator. How is it related to 200? and moreover to 4294967240

Comment: @dmcr_code - `0011 1000` is +56. (0011 = 3) * 16 + (1000 = 8) = 56. If you make it negative then you will have to get `2`s complement of 56 plus 1. `0011 1000` is `1100 0111` in `2`s complement. Add 1 then you have `1100 1000`. This is the representation of both 200 and -56 in an 8 bit signed char. Promote it to signed int then you'll end up with a lot of `1`s in front of it to preserve signness (again by virtue of `2`s complement). The value `4294967240` is the equivalent of `-56` when stored in signed int.